# Is this approach to generating a "random" number from a sha512 hash effective?

Tags: php, hash, cryptography, sha

I'm looking to run a small raffle but i'd like people to be able to verify that the number chosen was fair. I know some sites use a "Provably Fair" system to achieve this where user input is combined with a secret string which is then hashed to determine a winning number. Once the secret string is released, participants can verify using the hash that the correct winner was chosen.

From a sha512 hash a "random" number from 0-n (n varies in length but is 255 at most) should be generated to determine the winner. This is what I thought up:

Creating an array of n length and inserting pairs of characters that can appear in a sha hash. If n was 255 for example, the array would have: `array('aa','ab','ac'...'fd','fe','ff'...'97','98','99')`. Basically it'd have every combination of two characters using a-f and 0-9.

It'd then look at the first two characters of the hash and use array_search to see if that pair exists in the array. If it does, it's index is the number picked, otherwise it moves over to the next pair of characters and searches those. In the rare scenario it doesn't find a match it'll continually hash itself and use the new hash returned to continue the search.

```
$values = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
$numbers = array();
$ENTRANTS = 50;
$rand =  md5(uniqid(rand(), true)); //This would instead be $secret . $user_input
$hash = hash('sha512',$rand); 

$values_index = 0;
$current = $values[$values_index];
$options = 0;
while ($options < $ENTRANTS){
    $remaining = ($ENTRANTS - $options > 15)? 16: $ENTRANTS-$options;
    for ($n=0; $n < $remaining ;$n++){
        array_push($numbers, $current . $values[$n]);
        $options++;
    }

    $values_index++;
    $current = $values[$values_index];
}

$outcomes = array();
$winning = null;
$i = 0;

while (empty($winning)){

    while ($i+1 < 64 && empty($winning)){
        $combo = $hash[$i] . $hash[$i+1];
        $number = array_search($combo,$numbers);
        if ($number !== false){
            $winning = $number;
        }

        $i++;
    }

    if (!empty($winning)){
        echo "<pre>" . print_r($numbers,true) . "</pre>";
        echo $hash . "<br>" . $winning;
    }
    else {
        echo "re-hashing" . "<br>";
        $hash = hash("sha512",$hash);
        $i = 0;
    }
}
```

This is working when tested but I'm unsure if it is effectively generating a random number. Are the characters in a sha512 hash for the most part evenly and unpredictably distributed? If you can see any issues with this or have any advice on how it could be improved please let me know!

Comment: Cross posted to http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14431/is-this-approach-to-generating-a-random-number-from-a-sha512-hash-effective

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a cryptographic question and was posted to Crypo Stack Exchange - http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/14431/is-this-approach-to-generating-a-random-number-from-a-sha512-hash-effective

Answer (score 3):

The best way - as always in crypto - is not to roll your own security if it can be avoided. As your random number generator [`rand()` is not cryptographically secure](https://www.php.net/rand) (see the Notes section). Applying a hash on it won't make this random number generator secure. Actually, it is as good as impossible to make a good RNG from a (set of) bad ones.

Instead it is much better to use [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`](https://www.php.net/openssl_random_pseudo_bytes). There is [no need to perform any post processing on the bytes you get from that random number generator](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26206/should-i-use-urandom-or-openssl-random-pseudo-bytes) - at least not to add cryptographic strength.